# Python - product of two field with a foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I would like to know how to calculate the product of two field : score in FeatureInfo and ratio in Feature.

When I'm saving my FeatureInfo in my admin panel, it's not updating my field total. How can the field total be updated?

**models.py**

```
class Feature(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, null=True)
    ratio = models.IntegerField(null=True)

class FeatureInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, null=True)
    score = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    feature = models.ForeignKey(Feature, on_delete="CASCADE")
    _total = models.IntegerField(db_column='total')

    @property
    def total(self):
        return self.score * self.feature.score
```

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(FeatureInfo)
class FeatureInfoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ('id', 'feature', 'score', 'name', 'total')

    readonly_fields = ('id', 'total')
    list_filter = ('feature',)
    list_display = list_filter
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a property.

```
class FeatureInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, null=True)
    score = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    feature = models.ForeignKey(Feature, on_delete="CASCADE")

    @property
    def total(self):    
        return self.score * self.feature.ratio
```

Comment: When I'm saving my FeatureInfo in my admin panel, it's not updating total. Check my question I've updated it

Comment: Why would you expect anything to be saved in the database?

Comment: I will need the result of this calculation in the returns of my API call

Comment: Fine. That doesn't have anything to do with saving it in the database. You haven't written anything to save it, and you don't need to as it is trivial to calculate.